# android mvvm massive number of observers

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin

this is a very subjective question.
I'm finally getting more used to MVVM (Model View Viewmodel) (or at least I think so), and whats happening now is that I'm adding more and more MutableLiveData objects in the ViewModel and observing then right from the Activity onCreate.
I'm not truly sure if that's beneficial, or if that's noise from MVVM, or even if I'm taking a wrong approach, or even worst, there might be too much responsibilities to my class.
This is one of my methods called from onCreate which connects the observers:

```
private fun observeViewModel() {
    preferencesViewModel.selectedDay.observe(this, Observer { refreshMarkers() })

    viewModel.startPosition.observe(this, Observer { startPositionChanged(it) })
    viewModel.finishPosition.observe(this, Observer { finishPositionChanged(it) })
    viewModel.isShowingProgress.observe(this, Observer { progressDialogStateChanged(it) })
    viewModel.directionLine.observe(this, Observer { plotRoute(it) })
    viewModel.weathers.observe(this, Observer { if (it != null) showWeathers(it) })
    viewModel.isShowingTopBar.observe(this, Observer { if (it == true) showTopBar() else hideTopBar() })
    viewModel.shouldFinish.observe(this, Observer { if (it == true) finish() })
    viewModel.error.observe(this, Observer { if (it != null) showErrorDialog(it) })
    viewModel.actionRequest.observe(this, Observer { if (it != null) showActionRequest(it) })
    viewModel.permissionRequest.observe(this, Observer { if (it != null) requestPermissions(it) })
}
```

So my question is, is this expected on MVVM with LiveData?
Is there an approach which will lead to a more clean code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using kotlin what about using sealed class and using some state instead.

For example:

```
sealed class ScreenState {
    class Loading : ScreenState ()
    class Idle(var data: Any) : ScreenState ()
    class Dummy(val dummy: Any) : ScreenState ()
    ...
}
```

From your viewmodel

```
private val liveData: MutableLiveData<ScreenState> = MutableLiveData()
...
liveData.value = Idle(Any())
...
liveData.value = Loading()
```

From your view/controller

```
viewModel.liveData.observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let {
            when (it) {
                is ScreenState.Start -> ...
                is ScreenState.Idle -> ...
                is ScreenState.Dummy -> ...
            }
        }
    })
```

You may even use generic with sealed class

```
sealed class DataRequestState<T> {
    class Start<T> : DataRequestState<T>()
    class Success<T>(var data: T) : DataRequestState<T>()
    class Error<T>(val error: Throwable) : DataRequestState<T>()
}
```

This may help make things a bit cleaner and readable!

Comment: Cool! it seems interesting, gonna try it